# SAS Token - Azure IoTHub

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I use an Azure IoTHub to receive data from my devices.
To authorize theses devices to send data on my iothub, I generate and specify for each one a SAS Token.

Several time during my test, even after specifying an expiration time of 1month, I had to re-generate a new SAS Token again before the first one expired.

I would like to know what is the maximum expiry time accepted by the IotHub ?
Is there some scenario that cancels a SAS Token before the expiration date ?

Comment: how you generate the sas token ? i did with the azure cli command `z iot hub generate-sas-token -d mydevice -n myhub` and i am getting the sas token but when i use it for the rest call in header Authorization then i am getting ErrorCode:IotHubUnauthorizedAccess;Unauthorized in the response, can you help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Azure Device Explorer, the maximum value is 365 days.

Token seems not able to be canceled but you can disable the specified device to [mitigates the risks of using tokens with long expiry times](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-security#security-tokens).

Comment: what is the advantage of using SAS token over X509 certificate ? I need help to understand it.

Comment: @kudlatiger Simply to generate and use, no need to acquire a certificate and 
 upload either a certificate thumbprint or a certificate authority (CA) to Azure IoT Hub. No functional difference. Which one to choose depends on your condition, for example, your device support certificate or not? Use one of two, not both. Ref ["Control access to IoT Hub".](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-security)

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT  My device support certificates, but there is cost issues to get CA certificates, but we are planning to use DPS (Device Provisioning Service) and it seems like it must be done with only certificate!

Answer (score 0):

If you specify a SAS token that has an 'se' of one month from now, NOTHING will make it unsuitable.  I might suggest that you get the sas token's 'se' value and plug it into a web page that does utc calculations.  For instance https://www.mbari.org/utc-calculator is one I have used in the past.

Plug the number into the box next to UTC seconds then hit recompute.  The expiration time should be listed above.

I mention this so that you can check if you’ve generated your se appropriately.

A more interesting question would be why do you think you need to generate a new SAS token?  Did you receive some error from the telemetry request?   It might not be that your token has expired.   In addition what protocol were you using to talk to the hub?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you are not using the Microsoft SDK to connect your devices to the Azure IoT hub.

If you would be just as happy to generate the SAS tokens in your code then there is a sample, in C++, of how to do this for the Azure IoT hub that you can find here: https://github.com/markrad/Azure-IoT-ESP8266.

Check the .ino file for an example of how to use it. The code is implemented in the cpp, c and h files in that project.